# access to a samba folder within Stata on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, stata, samba, smb, ubuntu-13.10

I want to access to a samba folder to use it within Stata 13, so read and save data.

I'm quite new to ubuntu, so I do not know much about it. But I've googled and I've found how to mount and access a samba folder, but I can not understand if the Stata command `use` can handle such folders.

I've tried the following, without success

```
/home/federico/.gvfs/federico on karl.stats.ucl.ac.uk/stata_shared/Thin10/THIN10_1201/

/home/federico/.gvfs/federico%20on%20karl.stats.ucl.ac.uk/stata_shared/Thin10/THIN10_1201/"

/home/federico/.gvfs/karl.stats.ucl.ac.uk/stata_shared/Thin10/THIN10_1201/

smb://stats;federico@karl.stats.ucl.ac.uk/federico/stata_shared/Thin10/THIN10_1201/

smb://federico@karl.stats.ucl.ac.uk/federico/stata_shared/Thin10/THIN10_1201/

smb://karl.stats.ucl.ac.uk/federico/stata_shared/Thin10/THIN10_1201/
```

Can someone please tell me if this is possible or it is a total waste of time?

Comment: I don't know what a Samba folder is, but the Stata command (not function)  `use` reads in Stata dataset files in Stata's own proprietary format. It can do that over the internet.

Comment: That's exactly what I'd like to do: read a .dta file which is located in a folder on a server, of which those I gave above are the addresses (various version of the same one). I've tried e.g., `use "/home/federico/.gvfs/federico on karl.stats.ucl.ac.uk/stata_shared/Thin10/THIN10_1201/dataset.dta
", replace` and did not work.

Comment: So, what happens precisely? Can you give someone a reproducible example? I am not using the same OS, so I can't help test.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me (Stata 13 on Ubuntu box, connecting to Win Server 2008) is a command:

```
use "/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=SERVER_NAME,share=DRIVE_LETTER$/PATH/DATASET_NAME.dta"
```

With your input in places of capitalized names.

Comment: thanks radek, but this still puzzles me: still can't figure out what has to go in place of the upper case words. (1) Is the SERVER_NAME either` karl` or `karl..stats.ucl.ac.uk` or something else? (2) I dont' have the folder `/run/user/1000/gvfs` while instead I have the hidden folder `/home/federico/.gvfs/` (3) the smb address of the folder I have does not have any DRIVE_LETTER

Comment: @Federico Federico Ad.1 - being on local network I just use 'karl'. Ad. 2 - that's a little bit of a mystery to me. I haven't created this folder (some automagic I presume..) and it is empty till I connect to servers. Perhaps you could first use 'Browse Network' on ubuntu and try to get to the folders where your data is located.. and then try this path from within Stata? Ad. 3 - In that case - it can probably be omitted.

Comment: still haven't figured it out (1) I use `karl` now (2) I use `/home/federico/.gvfs/` instead of `/run/user/1000/gvfs` since I have Ubuntu 12.04, for which that one is the mounting point, I guess (3) the `share=` part I do not have any clue on how to fill that, I've tried lots of addresses' combinations